# React Material UI - Handle nav tabs when no children match the provided value

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I have a NavBar in my app which uses the [Material UI v5 - Nav tabs](https://mui.com/components/tabs/#nav-tabs) component with React Router v4. So when you navigate to something like `/about-us`, it will read that from the url and then change to that tab.

**The problem**

I have child pages, such as `/about-us/john`, `/about-us/deborah` but when I navigate to those pages, I get an error like this:

> MUI: The `value` provided to the Tabs component is invalid.
>
> None of the Tabs' children match with "/about-us/john".
>
> You can provide one of the following values: /, /about-us.

You'll see in the sample code section below my current approach, I'm thinking if there's a way to have a list of "valid" tab URLs but then am unsure of how to handle when there are child pages as described above.

**The desired outcome**

When I navigate to a URL like `/about-us/john`, it:

- Won't throw the above error.
- [Nice to have] Still highlight the `About Us` tab.

**Sample code**

```js
// NavBar.tsx
import { Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import Tabs from '@mui/material/Tabs';
import Tab from '@mui/material/Tab';

export const NavBar = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const currentTab = location.pathname;

  return (
    <Tabs value={currentTab} >
      <Tab label="Home" value="/" to="/" component={Link} />
      <Tab label="About Us" value="/about-us" to="/about-us" component={Link} />
    </Tabs>
  );
}
```

```js
// App.tsx
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import NavBar from './NavBar';
import Home from './Home';
import AboutUs from './AboutUs';
import AboutUsDetail from './AboutUsDetail';

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <NavBar />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/about-us">
          <AboutUs />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/about-us/:name">
          // Uses `useParams` from react-router-dom to extract the name.
          <AboutUsDetail />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Comment: Great question, I had a similar issue but there were no questions in SO matching with the keywords I was using to search for this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Issue

When matching and rendering a more deeply "nested" path, i.e. `"/about-us/john"` there is no specified matching `Tab` component `value` prop to render the tab correctly.

## Solution

Taking your sample `NavBar` you effectively need only match against the "root" path segment of any route, in this case, either `"/"` or `"/about-us"`. There are likely several ways to get this, i.e. string splitting, REGEX, etc... The following example uses a REGEX with a capturing group to grab the first segment. `/^(\/[^\/]*)/g` matches from the start of the string matching a `"/"` and includes all characters until the end of the string or the next `"/"` character.

```js
console.log([..."/".matchAll(/^(\/[^/]*)/g)][0][1]);
console.log([..."/about-us".matchAll(/^(\/[^/]*)/g)][0][1]);
console.log([..."/about-us/john".matchAll(/^(\/[^/]*)/g)][0][1]);
```

```
const NavBar = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  const [[, currentRoot]] = location.pathname.matchAll(/^(\/[^/]*)/g);

  return (
    <Tabs value={currentRoot}>
      <Tab label="Home" value="/" to="/" component={Link} />
      <Tab label="About Us" value="/about-us" to="/about-us" component={Link} />
    </Tabs>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit react-material-ui-handle-nav-tabs-when-no-children-match-the-provided-value]

[image]

Just an unrelated side-note regarding rendering routes into the `Switch`, you can avoid the unnecessary use of the `exact` prop by properly ordering the routes from more specific paths to less specific paths. If no higher, more specific route above matches then matching continues until the least specific match is found and rendered.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/about-us/:name">
    <AboutUsDetail />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/about-us">
    <AboutUs />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/">
    <Home />
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

Comment: This is fantastic thanks @Drew Reese! Appreciate the side-note, I remember reading that in the docs and forgot to apply it, will update the code to match! One small last thing, I am using Typescript for my project and am getting this error with the ReGex line `Type 'RegExpExecArray | null' is not an array type.ts(2461)`, how would you go about solving this?

Comment: @TroyPoulter I'm not super familiar with Typescript, but using `String.prototype.matchAll` seems to *not* yield this TS linting error. Updated answer and linked codesandbox.

Answer (score 2):

The `Tab` component takes an exact value and not a path like what `Route` does, so the dynamic part `:name` in `/about-us/:name` is not understandable by `Tabs`.

I have a workaround in case you want the error you mentioned to disappear from the console.
you can add another invisible `Tab` that would hold a value of the current `pathname`, so your `Tabs` will always have a match.

First, add the following CSS class for hiding the extra `Tab` to your `app.css` file or any file, and make sure to import it

```
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1000px;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then, add the extra `Tab`

```
import { Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import Tabs from '@mui/material/Tabs';
import Tab from '@mui/material/Tab';

const NavBar = () => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const currentTab = location.pathname;
    return (
        <Tabs value={currentTab} >
            <Tab label="Home" value="/" to="/" component={Link} />
            <Tab label="About Us" value='/about-us' to='/about-us' component={Link} />
            <Tab className="hidden" label="*" value={currentTab} to={currentTab} component={Link} />
        </Tabs>
    );
}

export default NavBar
```

I'm using the following versions of libs

"react": "^17.0.2"
"react-dom": "^17.0.2"
"@mui/material": "^5.2.1"
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"

Comment: Ahh very nice I get what you mean! I applied what you suggested and yep that does remove the console error. Though it also removes the underline beneath the tab, which would be nice to have back if possible. Also, can this be adapted to have it highlight one of the tabs when on a child page? Happy for it to be custom matching as some children pages may not have the tab name in it. An example would be `/our-people/John`, I'd want the `About Us` tab to appear selected ideally.